# Wordpress Search Query not returning User

Tags: wordpress

When I search for a User by their first name, all of their posts show up in the dashboard. When I search for that same User and add their last name, it does not show up at all. Not sure why this is happening only for this author. I have made all settings the same as other Users who have written posts as well.

Here's my first search URL and query, which returns all posts written by this User.
http://trochia.org/?s=dani

When I add her last name, there are no results.
http://trochia.org/?s=dani+nichols

Here's another User, no issue with only first name or with a combination of first and last name.
http://trochia.org/?s=fred
http://trochia.org/?s=fred+gladney

Comment: What gives you the idea that you should be able to search by author?  See this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29561/possible-to-search-by-author-name-with-default-wordpress-search-function  and this: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-all-user-posts-using-search-parameter-not-author-templatequery_posts

Comment: @cale_b b/c I can already search for multiple users. I just called it an author. A user writes a post, the posts are searchable by key words in the query.

Comment: That doesn't clarify your question.  Your question does not mention plugins or custom code.  In the absence of custom code, **WordPress does not** include the "author" (or "user") when it searches, therefore it will *not* find posts by a given author.

Comment: @cale_b then how am I returning posts written by all the other Users or Author. Here's an example:
http://d5a.aac.myftpupload.com/?s=fred+gladney

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
function atom_search_where($where){
global $wpdb;
if (is_search())
$where .= "OR (t.name LIKE '%".get_search_query()."%' AND {$wpdb-  >posts}.post_status = 'publish')";
return $where;
}

function atom_search_join($join){
global $wpdb;
if (is_search())
$join .= "LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} tr ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID  = tr.object_id INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} tt ON  tt.term_taxonomy_id=tr.term_taxonomy_id INNER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id";
return $join;
}

function atom_search_groupby($groupby){
global $wpdb;

// we need to group on post ID
$groupby_id = "{$wpdb->posts}.ID";
    if(!is_search() || strpos($groupby, $groupby_id) !== false) return         $groupby;

// groupby was empty, use ours
if(!strlen(trim($groupby))) return $groupby_id;

// wasn't empty, append ours
return $groupby.", ".$groupby_id;
} 

add_filter('posts_where','atom_search_where');
add_filter('posts_join', 'atom_search_join');
add_filter('posts_groupby', 'atom_search_groupby');
```